# Making md5sum understand file names with spaces

Tags: shell-script, python, filenames, quoting, arguments

I need to use `md5sum` in Python by using pipe to calculate checksum for a bunch of .mp3 files... is there a command which ignore whitespaces in filenames on the command line of `md5sum` program?

For example:

```
import os
def index(directory):
    stack = [directory]
    files = []
    while stack:
        directory = stack.pop()
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            fullname = os.path.join(directory, file)
            if fullname.endswith('mp3'):
                files.append(fullname)
            if os.path.isdir(fullname) and not os.path.islink(fullname):
                stack.append(fullname)
    return files

def check(directory):
    files = index(directory)
    hvalues = []
    for x in files:
        cmd = 'md5sum' + ' ' + x
        fp = os.popen(cmd)
        res = fp.readline()
        hvalues.append(res)
        stat = fp.close() # What to do with stat?
    return hvalues
```

Command `cmd = 'md5sum' + ' ' + x` won't work as it should on files that include whitespaces or special characters, because 'md5sum' tool lacks the ability of properly handling (hashing) files with whitespaces in filenames.

Comment: Could you clarify your question with an example? How are you passing the filenames?

Comment: I've added code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a lack of abilities in the `md5tool` but a general command line restriction. Arguments are separated by spaces. So if you pass a file name containing spaces to `md5sum` it will interpret each token as a single file. You can get around that by surrounding the file name with quotation marks.
That said, try replacing the line

```
cmd = 'md5sum' + ' ' + x
```

with

```
cmd = 'md5sum' + ' "' + x + '"'
```

and your command line call will look like

```
md5sum "file name with spaces.mp3"
```

Thus, `md5sum` will calculate the hash without complaining.

Answer (score 3):

As @binfalse points out, the problem is not in the `md5sum` program, but the way you invoked it.  Your code is actually bad on several levels:

1. You assembled a shell command without escaping.  In the worst case, that could lead to the execution of a completely unintended command if one of the filenames happens to be cleverly crafted.  That would be horrible, unless you are writing a single-use throwaway script.
2. The `os.popen()` function has been [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) since Python 2.6.  The recommended replacement is [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).  Be sure to pass a list as the `args` parameter, not a concatenated string, to avoid the shell-escaping problem previously mentioned.

   ```
   def check(directory):
       files = index(directory)
       hvalues = []
       for f in files:
           cmd = ['md5sum', f]
           proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
           hvalues.append(proc.stdout.readline())
           proc.stdout.close()
           stat = os.waitpid(proc.pid, 0)
       return hvalues
   ```
3. Better yet, use Python's [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/hashlib.html) to calculate the hashes.

Comment: Thank you for your advices! I'm actually currently learning Python, so this is a throwaway pipe-learning script, but in any case your advices are invaluable for me!

Comment: By 'escaping' do you reffer on adding the try/except clause?

Comment: @Reloader No: “escaping” means using quotes in the shell fragment, so that the shell knows which spaces separate arguments and which spaces are part of an argument. The spaces and other special characters that are part of a file name need to be escaped, i.e. quoted in some fashion.

Comment: Can you help me in replacing os.popen() with subprocess.Popen()?

Comment: I'm getting `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not defined` although I declared `from subprocess import Popen, PIPE` in the first line...